# How can I change the view output based on a value?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

When I get a [list of my recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rKXQ.png) from the API to the MVC, I have a some columns like **totalTimeUnitId** that have integer values instead of their actual unit(grams, kg, etc.). I am trying to figure out how to write code so that instead of 1, my view will return, for example 'g'.

I have little to no experience at all in working with views and I could not figure out a way to accomplish this.

```
 <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.recipeIngredientUnitId)
 </td>
```

For example in the code above, I would suppose that I need an @if clause that checks if item.recipeIngredientUnitId is 1, then if it is 2 and so on and it will eventually display the right unit. However, the syntax is quite an impediment for me and a little help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: why not have a property on your model that maps the id for you

Comment: How would you suggest that I'd make it? At the moment I wrote the following code in my model class, but it is not working: `public class Recipe
    {...
        public string totalTimeUnitId { get; set; }
                public Recipe(...int totalTimeUnitId,...)
        {...
            if(totalTimeUnitId==1)
            this.totalTimeUnitId = "g";
          
        }`

Comment: if you used a full property for your unit id, you could set your unit when the unit id gets set: https://jsfiddle.net/k2a5pmy6/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After inserting the code you sent, my values now only show "0". The code, in theory, should work. I will keep looking into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pete's code helped me out.

I added this in my Model class:

```
 private int _totalTimeUnitId;

    public int TotalTimeUnitId
    {
        get
        {
            return _totalTimeUnitId;
        }

        set
        {
            _totalTimeUnitId = value;

            switch (_totalTimeUnitId)
            {
                case 1:
                    TotalTimeUnit = "min";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TotalTimeUnit = "hour(s)";
                    break;
                default:
                    TotalTimeUnit = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

To connect your model and the View:

### In the View (.cshtml) file

```cs
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers // imports tag helpers
@model Recipe //this way you import your model to view

//then use the property of this model to display `totalTimeUnitId`  

<td>
     @Model.totalTimeUnitId
</td>
```

### In Controller class

```cs
public IActionResult SomeName()
{
     Recipe r = new Recipe();
     return View(r); //you need to pass an instance of Recipe type
}
```

Comment: I already had this: `@model IEnumerable<UI.Models.Recipe>`. My question was: Based on the value from the Model, how can I insert another value in the View? Basically, if the model has value 1, the view should show Kg.

Comment: Oh, I see. What if you create an Enum with such info inside your class? And then just read it from View?